# Error rate in comparing clusterings or partitions

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory, variance, clustering

Given $n,k \in \mathbb{N}, \ k < n$, we assume that there is an optimal partition $P$ of $n$ elements into $k$ bins.

Given a random partition $Q$, what is the expectation value $E(r)$ of $r$, the number of elements placed in incorrect bins by a random partition. The order of the bins doesn't matter.

**Background**

The goal is to estimate the quality in clustering by comparing several clusterings generated by stochastic gradient descent. If they are highly correlated, then we have a good clustering. If they are not, then the elements would seem to be largely independent.

I would like to calculate the expectation value of $r$ for random clusterings in order to set a baseline for determining whether the algorithmically generated clusters do much better than random clusters.

**What I've tried**

I think that my trouble may have something to do with the bin order not mattering, and therefore the optimal pairing of bins for comparison between $P$ and $Q$ is not necessarily obvious.

Let's consider the number of partitions with a given $r$ value.
There are $k!$ orderings for the bins. For each of these, we will have $(n-r)$  elements in the one correct bin for them, and $r$ elements in any of $(k-1)$ incorrect bins. The number of ways of doing this is

$$
k!\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r
\end{array}\right)\left(k-1\right)^{r}
$$

There are $k^n$ different assignments of elements to bins, so, according to my reasoning,  the probability of the error rate being a given value $r$ is

$$\frac{k!\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r
\end{array}\right)\left(k-1\right)^{r}}{k^{n}}
$$

and we have

$$
E(r)=\sum_{r=0}^{r=n}r\left(\frac{k!\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r
\end{array}\right)\left(k-1\right)^{r}}{k^{n}}\right)
$$

This is problematic since, with the bins unordered, $r$ shouldn't reach $n$ (or tighter bounds depending on $n$ and $k$) since the bin order can be chosen so at least $1$ element is in the correct bin. However, the $r=n$ term in the sum above is non-zero, and contributes incorrectly to the $E(r)$. Besides, this formula very often produces $E(r)>n$,
which is impossible. Dropping the $k!$ and using

$$
E(r)=\sum_{r=0}^{r=n}r\left(\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
r
\end{array}\right)\left(k-1\right)^{r}}{k^{n}}\right)
$$

gives much more reasonable results, but I'm having trouble justifying ignoring permutations of the bins.

**Another approach**

Compare the graphs, $G(P)$ and $G(Q)$ with two nodes connected if they are in the same cluster. We might provide some measure of $r$ for a given partition by considering

$$R = G(P^c)\cap G(Q^c)$$

with $c$ denoting the complement. I'd like to explore the value of

$$\text{comp}(P,Q)=\frac{\#R}{\#P\cdot\#Q}$$

where  $\#$ denotes cardinality, as akin to some product related to $r^2$ as a measure of variance in the partitions. There is complication in that this depends on both $r$ and the cluster sizes.